# FB Login Button Does Not Redirect After Login In IE

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook

I am having issues with FB login from our website.

If you are not already logged into Facebook in the current session and you click the "Login using Facebook" button on our website it opens the FB login popup window.

User enters their username and password and clicks next in the popup window.

If the user has not previously granted permissions, the permissions page opens up, user clicks "allow" and the next page loads as blank white, the popup does not close and the user is not logged into our website.

If the user has previously granted permissions the page following the fb login screen in the popup loads as blank white, the popup does not close and the user is not logged into our website.

This issue only occurs in IE (seen in both 7 & 8). The login process works perfetly in FF and Chrome.

Has anyone else seen similar behavior? Any suggestions to fix it? Thank you for your assitance.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a documented bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12112).

I was able to find a work around for the issue by following the suggestion of commenter number 2, Daniel Robert. By moving the `fb-root` element to immediately after the `<body>` tag so that it is the first element the issue is resolved. Strange but it works.